# How to upgrade from Win 8 N to win 8.1 N

Tags: windows-8-upgrade

How do I upgrade a Windows 8 N 32-bit system to Windows 8.1 N? I can't find anything on the Microsoft website.

Comment: What is this `N` you mentioned?

Comment: [Windows 8.1 N editions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-8/n-editions)

Comment: You should be able to install it by finding it on the Windows Store.  You must have all released updates for the update to appear.  Otherwise using a generic Windows 8.1 N license and a Windows 8.1 installation media disk and then changing the license back to your current Windows 8.0 license should also work.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's the same as in the other editions...

1. Install all Windows updates through "Control Panel -> Windows Update".
2. Start the Windows Store, there should be a tile to click on which starts the download.
3. Followe the instructions of the installer.

Answer (score 0):

Head to Microsoft's 8.1 N page here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-8/n-editions

Click "Download the Upgrade" related to the edition of 8 N you currently have (actually probably doesn't matter which link you use) to download the Windows Upgrade Assistant.

> Upgrade Assistant is a free download that scans your PC, desktop apps,
>   and connected devices to see if they'll work with a later version of
>   Windows, and then provides a free compatibility report. Depending on
>   the version of Windows you're running, you can also use Upgrade
>   Assistant to buy, download, and install Windows online.